# How to properly use custom service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to move my controller logic to a service. I've added DataService and injected $http. Then loadData() method returns JSON. I've injected this service into a TestController and called mentioned function, but it doesn't work. The same simple logic worked correctly from a controller. What should I improve? :)

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.controller('TestController', TestController);
app.service('DataService', DataService);

function TestController(DataService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.personalInfo = DataService.loadData();
}

function DataService($http) {
    var store = this;
    store.personInfo = [];

    store.loadData = function(){
        $http.get('data.json')
        .success(function(data){
        store.personInfo = data;
    })
    .error(function(){
        store.personInfo = "Error occured";
    });

    return store.personInfo;
    };
}
```

My view looks as easy as that:

```
<body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestController as test">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <p ng-repeat="item in test.personalInfo" ng-bind="item.firstname"></p>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: the first step is to define what you mean by the term "does not work" : )

Comment: and, if you expect the `loadData` to return anything but `[]`, then it won't because the call to `$http` is asynchronous. You need to set your `vm.personalInfo` when the `success`/`error` callback is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `store.loadData` returning undefined before response come from backend. so use this code:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.controller('TestController', TestController);
app.service('DataService', DataService);

function TestController(DataService) {
    var vm = this;
    DataService.loadData().then(function(data) {
            vm.personalInfo = data.data
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

function DataService($http) {
    var store = this;
    store.personInfo = [];

    store.loadData = function() {
        return $http.get('data.json')

    };
}
```

Comment: It looks reasonable, but still doesn't work. See here http://plnkr.co/edit/wgcAFS4y1t0z1v7fFgvl?p=preview

Comment: use data.data in controller see plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/2mR6PtFbS927iRApveL7?p=preview